# Borrar en IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, html5

Estoy intentando aprender algo de HTML5 y, practicando con indexedDB he creado un montón de objetos. Se como borrar la información de los registros, pero
¿Cómo se borran todos esto objetos que he creado durante las pruebas?

Mi servidor WEB es la aplicación Webstation de un NAS

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Saludos podria hacer algo como esto:

```
var req = indexedDB.deleteDatabase(mi_DB);
req.onsuccess = function () {
    console.log("Borrado exitosamente !!");
};
req.onerror = function () {
    console.log("error - nose ha borrado la BD");
};
req.onblocked = function () {
    console.log("Operacion bloqueada - nose ha borrado la BD");
};
```

Para mayor referencia: [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBFactory#deleteDatabase)

Comment: Muchas Gracias, Diego. Estaba atascado y no encontraba el comando. Me pongo a ello